# Why is flash sort O(n)?

Tags: sorting, complexity-theory

I am studying the flash sort algorithm and I could not find thorough explanations of why is it O(n). Isn't O(nlogn) the best possible complexity?

Answer (score 0):

The best is O(nlogn) in the general case, that is on completely random data. The flash sort algorithm assumes the data has a known distribution and thus can be partitioned, it also assume a multiprocessor achitecture.

Also, flash sort has worst-case O(N^2).